# NullPointer Exception when running Android Activity

Tags: java, android

I dont understand why my app keep crashing. THe google analytics keeps saying that this crash is the most common on my app and i cant fix it.  I have looked over the code multiple times and dont know how to fix the issue.

Here is error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19421)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5579)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.soloinc.meip.RecordRap.onClick(RecordRap.java:371)
... 14 more
```

Here is recordrap

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_rap);


    //instrument name from previous activity
    instrument_file_name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("instrument_file_name");
    instrument_title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("instrument_title");
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.instrument_title);
    tv.setText(instrument_title);    
    //getting buffer size for our audio specification
    bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);



    //setting listeners for seek bars
    seekBar1 = (SeekBar)(findViewById(R.id.seekBar1));
    seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(osbcl);
    seekBar2 = (SeekBar)(findViewById(R.id.seekBar2));
    seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(osbcl);


 // Get the AudioManager
    AudioManager audioManager =
    (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    // Set the volume of played media to maximum.
    audioManager.setStreamVolume (
    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
    audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC),
    0);


    //saving beats data in List

    if(savedInstanceState == null)
        new SaveInputStreamTask(this).execute();
}



  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
     // The rest of your onStart() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // The rest of your onStop() code.
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
  }

//Listener for seek bars
final SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener osbcl = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        if(arg0.getId() == R.id.seekBar1)
        {
            seekBar1Value = arg0.getProgress();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Beat Volume:"+seekBar1Value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            seekBar2Value = arg0.getProgress();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Lyrics Volume:"+seekBar2Value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        simultaneousPlay();//whenever volume value changes play audios again to show change in volume level
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {}
};
//initializing mediaplayer for playing beat 
private void initializePlayer()
{

    try
    {
        //int resID=getResources().getIdentifier(instrument_file_name.substring(0,instrument_file_name.length()-4), "raw", getPackageName());
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse(instrument_file_name));

        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                isPlayingInstrument = false;

            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
}
//return file name with current millisecond
private String getFilename()
{
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath,MEIP_FOLDER);

    if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdirs();
    }
    String temp = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + mixed_file_name + MEIP_FILE_EXT_WAV;
    recorded_rap_file_name = temp;
    return temp;
}
//return temporary fileName
private String getTempFilename()
{
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath,MEIP_FOLDER);

    if(!file.exists()){
            file.mkdirs();
    }

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + MEIP_TEMP_FILE);
}
//This function records user voice
private void startRecording()
{
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS,RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);
    recorder.startRecording();
    isRecording = true;

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                    saveLyricsPCMData(recorder);
                    //writePCMDataToFile(getTempFilename(),recorder);
            }
    },"AudioRecorder Thread");

    recordingThread.start();
}
//this function saves recording PCM data to temp file 
private void saveLyricsPCMData(AudioRecord ar)
{
    short data[] = new short[bufferSize];
    lyricsShortList.clear();

    int read = 0;

    while(isRecording)
    {
            read = ar.read(data, 0, bufferSize);               
            if(AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < read; k++)
                {
                    lyricsShortList.add(data[k]);
                }
            }
    }
}
//this function executes when user stop recording
private void stopRecording()
{
    if(null != recorder)
    {
            isRecording = false;

            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();

            recorder = null;
            recordingThread = null;
    }

    //writePCMToWaveFile(getTempFilename(),getFilename());
    //deleteTempFile();
}

//this function writes wav file header to out
private void WriteWaveFileHeader(FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,long byteRate) throws IOException 
{    
    byte[] header = new byte[44];

    header[0] = 'R';  // RIFF/WAVE header
    header[1] = 'I';
    header[2] = 'F';
    header[3] = 'F';
    header[4] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
    header[5] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[6] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[7] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[8] = 'W';
    header[9] = 'A';
    header[10] = 'V';
    header[11] = 'E';
    header[12] = 'f';  // 'fmt ' chunk
    header[13] = 'm';
    header[14] = 't';
    header[15] = ' ';
    header[16] = 16;  // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
    header[17] = 0;
    header[18] = 0;
    header[19] = 0;
    header[20] = 1;  // format = 1
    header[21] = 0;
    header[22] = (byte) channels;
    header[23] = 0;
    header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
    header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
    header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[32] = (byte) ((RECORDER_BPP*channels) / 8);  // block align
    header[33] = 0;
    header[34] = RECORDER_BPP;  // bits per sample
    header[35] = 0;
    header[36] = 'd';
    header[37] = 'a';
    header[38] = 't';
    header[39] = 'a';
    header[40] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
    header[41] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[42] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[43] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);

    out.write(header, 0, 44);
}   

//onClick listeners for all the buttons
@Override
public void onClick(View view) 
{
    final Chronometer myChronometer = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

    switch(view.getId())
    {

        case R.id.play_button:
            if(isPlayingInstrument == false)
            {
                if(player == null){initializePlayer();}
                isPlayingInstrument = true;
                player.start();
                myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

            }
        break;

        case R.id.pause_button:
line 366            player.pause();
            isPlayingInstrument = false;
        break;

        case R.id.stop_button:
    line 371        player.stop();
            player = null;
            isPlayingInstrument = false;
            play_thread_running = false;

        break;

        case R.id.start_recording_button:
            if(isRecording == false)
            {
                ((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.start_recording_button)).setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
                startRecording();
                myChronometer.start();

            }
        break;

        case R.id.stop_recording_button:
            stopRecording();
            myChronometer.stop();
            play_thread_running = false;
            ((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.start_recording_button)).setImageResource(R.drawable.button_record);
        break;

        case R.id.mix_and_play_button:
                simultaneousPlay();

        break;

        case R.id.save_recording_button:
            showDialog();       
        break;

        case R.id.share_button:
            share();
            break;
    }

}

public void share(){
    if( mixed_file_name == null || mixed_file_name.equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Save Your Song First!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("SHAREFILE", getFilename());
    Message msg = mShareHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.setData(data);
    mShareHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}   

//play beat and lyrics simultaneously
public void simultaneousPlay()
{
    if(play_thread_running == true){play_thread_running = false;}

     try
    {    
         beat_playing_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                play(buildShortArray(beatsShortList),seekBar1Value);    
            }
        });
         lyrics_playing_thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    play(buildShortArray(lyricsShortList),seekBar2Value);   
                }
            });
         beat_playing_thread.start();
         lyrics_playing_thread.start();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


//play an audio file
private void play(final short[] soundData, final int volume)
{
    short[] output = new short[soundData.length];
    // find the max:
    float max = 0;
    for (int i = 44; i < output.length; i++) 
    {
        if (Math.abs((soundData[i])) > max)
        {
            max = Math.abs((soundData[i]));
        }
    }
 // now find the result, with scaling:
    float a,c;
    for (int i = 44; i < output.length; i++) 
    {
        a = (float)(soundData[i]);
        c = Math.round(Short.MAX_VALUE * (a)/ max);

        if (c > Short.MAX_VALUE)
            c = Short.MAX_VALUE;
        if (c < Short.MIN_VALUE)
            c = Short.MIN_VALUE;
        output[i] = (short) c; 
    }
    AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 22050, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    play_thread_running = true;
    audioTrack.play();
    audioTrack.setStereoVolume((float)(volume/100.0f), (float)(volume/100.0f));
    int bufferSize = 512;
    ShortBuffer sb = ShortBuffer.wrap(output);
    short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < output.length-512 && play_thread_running == true; i = i+512)
    {
        sb.get(buffer, 0, 512);
        audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, 512);
    }
}
//this function mix audios
private byte[] mixSound() throws IOException 
{
    completeStreams(beatsShortList,lyricsShortList);
    short[] output = new short[beatsShortList.size()];

    // find the max:
    float max = 0;
    for (int i = 44; i < output.length; i++) 
    {
        if (Math.abs((beatsShortList.get(i)*(seekBar1Value/100.0f)) + (lyricsShortList.get(i)*(seekBar2Value/100.0f))) > max)
        {
            max = Math.abs((beatsShortList.get(i)*(seekBar1Value/100.0f)) + (lyricsShortList.get(i)*(seekBar2Value/100.0f)));
        }
    }

    // now find the result, with scaling:
    float a, b, c;
    for (int i = 44; i < output.length; i++) {
        a = beatsShortList.get(i)*(seekBar1Value/100.0f);
        b = lyricsShortList.get(i)*(seekBar2Value/100.0f);

        c = Math.round(Short.MAX_VALUE * (a + b)/ max);

        if (c > Short.MAX_VALUE)
            c = Short.MAX_VALUE;
        if (c < Short.MIN_VALUE)
            c = Short.MIN_VALUE;

        output[i] = (short) c; 
    }

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(output.length * 2);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    bb.asShortBuffer().put(output);
    byte[] bytes = bb.array();
    return bytes;
}

//convert inputstream to byte array
public static byte[] getBytesFromInputStream(InputStream is)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[0xFFFF];

        for (int len; (len = is.read(buffer)) != -1;)
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);

        os.flush();

        return os.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public void saveInputStream(InputStream is) throws IOException
{
    int n = 0;
    DataInputStream in1;
    in1 = new DataInputStream(is);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try 
    {

        while ((n = in1.read()) != -1) 
        {
            bos.write(n);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {   
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bos.toByteArray());
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    ShortBuffer sb = bb.asShortBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < sb.capacity(); i++) {
        beatsShortList.add(sb.get(i));
    }
}
//add zeros to shorter audio        
public void completeStreams(List<Short> l1,List<Short> l2)
{
    if(l1.size() > l2.size())
    {
        while(l1.size() != l2.size())
        {
            l2.add((short)0);
        }
    }
    if(l2.size() > l1.size())
    {
        while(l1.size() != l2.size())
        {
            l1.add((short)0);
        }
    }
}
//converts short list to short array
public short[] buildShortArray(List<Short> list)
{
    short[] arr = new short[list.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        arr[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
//overriding back button functionality
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
        if(player != null)
            player.stop();
        play_thread_running = false;
        //beat_playing_thread.stop();
        //lyrics_playing_thread.stop();
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    return true;
}

public void showDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("What's Your Song Name!");
    alert.setMessage("Song Name");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

      mixed_file_name = input.getText().toString();
        new SaveFileTask(RecordRap.this).execute();

          //progress = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "", "Mixing and Saving...");
          }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Canceled.
          }
        });
```

Comment: the issue is in the onClick method of RecordRap, at line 371, what is that line?

Comment: You're calling methods on `player` without checking if it's null first and you set `player` to null when stop is pressed.

Comment: Agreeing with @Baldy, player is null, hence the null pointer exception (at least if pressing stop twice)

Comment: how do i fix it and i wrote in the code where line 371 is

Comment: Either test for null or don't set it to null!

Comment: i am kind of new to programming so i dont know how i would go about doing it. Can you provie an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small re-factoring to address at least part of your NPE problem. I have no idea if this functionally correct since I'm not looking at your entire application but it should point you in the right direction. For the play logic, I'm assuming that sometimes your `initializePlayer()` method fails to set player to a non-null value based on your bug reports.

```
    case R.id.play_button:
        if(isPlayingInstrument == false) {
            if(player == null)
                initializePlayer();

            if(player != null) {
                isPlayingInstrument = true;
                player.start();
                myChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            }
        }
    break;

    case R.id.pause_button:
        if(player != null) {
            player.pause();
            isPlayingInstrument = false;
        }
        break;

    case R.id.stop_button:
        if(player != null) {
            player.stop();
            player = null;
            isPlayingInstrument = false;
            play_thread_running = false;
        }
        break;
```